# Transparent Overlay in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a transparent overlay, should work on top of other application window also using code below.
Problems are:
1) it doesn't work at the top of other application window.
2) background color is not transparent.

java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //-----
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams window_params=getWindow().getAttributes();
   // window_params.screenBrightness=1f;
    window_params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
    window_params.type=2006;
    getWindow().setAttributes(window_params); 
    //------
    view = new MyView(this);    //MyView view = new MyView(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    view.changeSomethingInWindow(); // keep an eye on this method
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  //setContentView(view); //setContentView(view ,new LayoutParams(200,400));
}
public class MyView extends View{

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    public void changeSomethingInWindow(){
        // get a reference of the activity
        Activity parent = (Activity)getContext();

        Window window = parent.getWindow();
        window.getWindowManager();
        window.setLayout(300, 400);     //window.setLayout(getHeight()/2, getWidth()/2);
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        //window = new Window(this, R.style.Theme_Transparent);
      //  window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(getWindowVisibility());
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY); 
        window.getWindowStyle();
        window.getDecorView();


    }
}
```

style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    <resources>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>  
</style>
```

`manifest.xml:android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"`  i have used this in manifest.xml

try to help me, to figure out the solution of this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: i am getting a black screen , but it is an overlay because if i click on this screen then corresponding application which is just behind this black screen, starts run as foreground.                              follow some steps :- 1. start emulator device, unlock that and come to the Home screen.                                                      2. then paste this code in eclipse and run it, and feel the output which i mentioned.                                                   note: android sdk version should be 14.0

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
 private static final int FLAGS = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL    |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN   |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN        |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE      |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS   |
                                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;

 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(0, FLAGS, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

 getWindowManager().addView (overlayView, params);
```

Remove FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE if you want receive touches. 
Pay attention to "addView" parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is remain same. what i want telling you, my code should reflect a small size window at the middle of emulator screen and rest part(home screen as background) should be transparent and accessible, and that small shaded window should present always at the top of other program's output screen as SYSTEM_OVERLAY.

Comment: find approximate view at the link given below :- http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&biw=1034&bih=618&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=fkeBHcugs6uGUM:&imgrefurl=http://www.freefullandroidapps.com/free-download-android-mobile-screenshot-er-2-v2-3-apk-app.html&docid=V1fdVL2oZ9NReM&imgurl=http://www.freefullandroidapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/1693a.jpg&w=307&h=512&ei=DHYsUO6qGcqmrAf2_IGwCw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=366&sig=115636019309508714938&page=4&tbnh=143&tbnw=86&start=54&ndsp=21&ved=1t:429,r:54,s:20,i:294&tx=62&ty=103

Comment: See at WindowManager.LayoutParams. The first parameter should be not 0, but WindowManager.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. Also patch AndroidManifest to allow it.  I can send you a sample application for show the CPU temperature always on the screen.

Comment: OGP the example you posted has expired and is no longer available.  Is there a way to get a copy of it?

Comment: OGP, thanks for reply , i will definitely try with that example.